# Extract numbers (not digits) from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract whole numbers (and not just digits) from a string
For example, 34681A Lincoln Street Surf City NJ 08008
should output only 08008, not 34681

I have tried with regex

```
$str = '34681A Lincoln Street Surf City NJ 08008';
$str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

but it also outputs 34681 which I don't need.

EDIT (as per comment) : The number can consist of any number of digits, but it should be a standalone number i.e. without any letters or symbols (comma or dot before after the number is acceptable)

Comment: You have to be more specific. What differentiates the number from normal words? Must they contain digits, may they contain only letters, should any letter be uppercase or is lowercase also allowed, should the number be of a fixed length or can they be of any length... Regular expressions need to be as specific as possible; if they are not then you will end up with stuff that you are not interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=[,.\s]))\d+(?=[,.\s]|$)
```

You can use `lookaheads` for this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD0sJ3/3

```
$re = "/(?:^|(?<=\\s))\\d+(?=\\s|$)/si";
$str = "34681A Lincoln Street Surf City NJ 08008";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

or thru replace

```
(?:^|(?<=[,.\s]))\d+(?=[,.\s]|$)\K|.
```

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/vD0sJ3/5)

```
$re = "/(?:^|(?<=[,.\\s]))\\d+(?=[,.\\s]|$)\\K|./i";
$str = "James 3, Aptt.27, 34681/A Lincoln St Surf City NJ 08008";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Almost the answer I need. How to improve this so that it considers numbers before/after comma & dot also as output. For example, 
$str = 'James 3, Aptt.27, 34681/A Lincoln St Surf City NJ 08008';
to output
3
27
08008

Answer (score 4):

The regex for a word consisting wholly of digits, is:

```
\b\d+\b
```

You can use that to extract them.

The `\b` marker represents a zero-character transition from word character to non-word-character (or start/end of string) in either direction.

---

See, for example, the following code:

```
$str = 'James 7, Apt 27, 34681A Lincoln St Surf City NJ 08008';
$rc = preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/', $str, $matches);
echo "Count = $rc\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $rc; $i++) {
    echo "Item $i is '" . $matches[0][$i] . "'\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
Count = 3
Item 0 is '7'
Item 1 is '27'
Item 2 is '08008'
```

---

Now that's tailored specifically for your original question but, if you have further requirements, it's a matter of adjusting the regular expression.

For example, per your edit:

> The number can consist of any number of digits, but it should be a standalone number i.e. without any letters or symbols (comma or dot before after the number is acceptable).

That regular expression can be done with lookaheads and lookbehinds, a rather more advanced facility of modern regex engines, as per the following code:

```
$str = '7, James 2-A 3, Apt 27, 34681A Lincoln St Surf City NJ 08008';
$rc = preg_match_all('/(?:^|(?<=[,.\s]))\d+(?=[,.\s]|$)/', $str, $matches);
echo "Count = $rc\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $rc; $i++) {
    echo "Item $i is '" . $matches[0][$i] . "'\n";
}
```

The section at the start, `(?:^|(?<=[,.\s]))`, is a non capturing group which matches either the start of the string `^` or a lookbehind requiring a character from the set consisting of `.`, `,` or white-space.

That's almost identical to the bit at the end, `(?=[,.\s]|$)`, which is a non-capturing group consisting of either end-of-string or a character from that afore-mentioned set.

All that remains then is the `\d+`, which *is* captured, hence the output of that program is:

```
Count = 4
Item 0 is '7'
Item 1 is '3'
Item 2 is '27'
Item 3 is '08008'
```

Just keep in mind that, as you add more rules to the mix, regular expressions can get quite complex. At some point, it may become preferable to write your own parser so that you have better control and readability.

Comment: Thanks. This satisfies my example string, but how to improve it if my string has 34681-A, A-34681, 34681/A, A/34681 etc. instead of simply 34681A. Space comma and dot are accepted punctuations, but not other symbols.

Comment: @Howard, if you want it to handle something different to what you stated in the question, ask another question, _fully_ specifying what you need. We're not mind-readers :-) But I'll update the answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did mean to extract numbers only, but forgot to gave an example consisting of symbols also

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```